# Briefly turning an output on when a switch is turned off

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm not sure if there's a simple way to do this, or even a way at all.

Basically what I have is a switch which is on, and two outputs.

The first output is very simple - it goes on when the switch is turned on, and off after a short delay when the switch is turned off. Easily achieved with redstone repeaters

The second output is more complex.

- When the switch is steady off, it has to be off.
- When the switch is steady on, it can be either on or off, it doesn't matter, apart from the first few seconds
- When the switch is turned on, the output must be off, at least for the first few seconds.
- When the switch is turned off, the output must be off, and then pulse on and off after a brief delay (which I need to be able to control)

If that makes any sense whatsoever?

Any suggestions appreciated

Jon

Comment: FYI, this is called an edge detector circuit, and is the falling edge variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a circuit that should work for you.

[image]

In this image, the lever (input) is off and the piston (output) is off.  You can tell the input is off because the torch above the lever is still on, which means it is not receiving power.  You can tell the output if off because, well, you get the idea there.

Turning the input on will do nothing to the output.  Turning the input off will wait according to how long you set the delay on the repeaters connected to the output, then briefly pulse the output. Add more repeaters to the output as needed.

Comment: @JonStory No problem, you can move things around to make it a bit more compact.  I just wanted to get a clear picture.